# Jquery scrolltop won't work with offset

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I got a small problem with jQuery, when the function runs for the first time it doesn't seem to notice the -60 px for my sticky header. After that, it works great, I have no clue what's wrong.

You can test it out for yourself here http://test.peekmanagement.com/

```
    $("#link_to_services").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#services").offset().top - 60
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Comment: it's not just the first time, for the next times, if you scroll up your page to the most beginning point and try scrolling down until the `Services` link is shown, then clicking on it will still show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggest in the comment, try something like this (not real js, but in 'metalanguage', just to explain):

```
     $('<div class="replaced-container" />')
        .height($actualHeader.height())
        .width($actualHeader.width())
        .appendTo($actualHeaderContainer);
```

And, on page scroll:

```
    if (pageScrollTop is > of the firstScene) {
       $('.replaced-container').show();
    } else {
     $('.replaced-container').hide();
    }
```

Comment: No problem, as soon i could, i'll manage to code a fiddle to explain.

Comment: Hi, actually i had not time, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the function on $(window).load, not at document ready.

Comment: I've understand the problem: because the header become 'sticky', as it is fixed, the offset().top that you calculate is not correct. You have to wrap the header in an extra div, or just append a 'replaced-container' and set it the actual header height and width, via jQuery method, so in the page every element do not affect the lack of height of the fixed header, because in fact the header height do not change. So, when the page scoll, the header is 'sticky', and the offset of all element remain the same. Plus, i've got a check in your code, and it has to refactor a bit...